# Adding JFXPanel to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I need to render a `JFXPanel` as a component inside `JPanel`.

My application works on JAVA1.6 only, I wrote code to render JFXPanel in JPanel and I didn't get any error but cant see any visible output.

I tried also by using BorderLayout as center.

I noticed also that in a line creating Scene() after that execution next line not get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into "Embedding JavaFX2 in Swing" sample here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-samples-2158687.html

Or read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE